# How do I compile all C files to object files at once to the same directory?

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to compile all the c files at once. ex) `aaa.c`,`bbb.c` -> `aaa.o`, `bbb.o` each independent.

My Make

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99
SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)

all:$(SRCS)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

but `make all` command does not work.

### How to compile all c file at once?

I changed to under the code, but still not working

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99
SRCS=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,%(SRCS))
all:$(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way: change `gcc -o ...` to `gcc -c -o ...`

Better way: make a list of the object files you want to build:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))
```

and then all you have to do is:

```
all: $(OBJS)
```

Comment: I change `all` to `all:$(OBJS)` and append `OBJS` under the `SRCS` but make still error occur.

Comment: @DWAhn: You made a typo in the `OBJS := ...` line.

Comment: Yes I follow your `OBJS` line

Comment: @DWAhn: **You made a typo. My line is `... $(SRCS))`; you transcribed `... %(SRCS))`.**

Answer (score 0):

simple and working Makefile:

```
TARGET ?= a.out
SRC_DIRS ?= ./src
INC_DIRS ?= ./include

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

LDLIBS :=  -L/usr/lib -lstdc++  -lfoo

INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@  $(LDLIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        $(RM) $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

-include $(DEPS)
```